# Не срабатывает :hover

Tags: hover, css

http://jsfiddle.net/8vk2rk6L/2/

При таком раскладе, **hover** отказывается работать. Если же ставить z-index, то при клике на Выбрать файл, не открывается окошко с выбором файла.

Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fsnq38dx/

Comment: Или так http://jsfiddle.net/8vk2rk6L/3/ (если брать разметку автора).

Comment: @soledar10, благодарю.